# Synchronize access to shell variables while using Gnu parallel (i.e. critical section in Gnu parallel)

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a `for` loop that I'd like to convert to `parallel`. However, I'm appending to a global (`bash`) array within my loop. What's the recommended way of dealing with this situation? Does `parallel` provide any form of synchronization between jobs besides `--keep-order`?

I thought about replacing my array with a combination of `flock` and `echo > some_shared_file`, but wanted to know if there's a standard way of implementing a "critical section" with `parallel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash only has "thread local" variables. There are no global variables that can be updated from different threads. All variables/arrays are copied to the subprocesses, and changes in one will not be reflected in another.

The more general answer -- if you had resources that actually could be updated from different processes -- would be to use `sem` which comes with GNU parallel.

Comment: `bash` *does* have global scope, but I see what you mean with the subprocesses. Thanks for the pointer to `sem`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Might be even more accurate to say bash doesn't have support for spawning threads at all, only forking new processes. So sharing global variables just doesn't make any sense.